# How to save contacts using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-contacts

Thanks for previous replies,

I am trying to add contacts using phone gap, I used `

```
var phoneNumbers = [];
phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('work', '1234567890', false);
phoneNumbers[1] = new ContactField('mobile', '1234567890123456', true); // preferred number
phoneNumbers[2] = new ContactField('home', '1234567890', false);
contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers; contact.save(onSaveSuccess,onSaveError);`
```

But this code are saving the **contacts** in Google. Instead of this i want to store in my local contact storage. is anything possible to store the contacts in local.

please guide me to figure out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function writeLocalStorage()
{
    window.localStorage.setItem("Username", "name");
    window.localStorage.setItem("ph_no", "no.");
    //here code for get the item.
 }
```

Probably you have to change the function body according to your requirment, I hope it work!

for more see [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage)

Comment: Thanks for immediate replies. How can we store the contacts using this code. can you explain me in brief .

Comment: with the help of chrome browser you can see the store data by tool->Developertool->localstarage->local files